# Parametrization of intersections

Tags: intersection, implicit

How may we find (at least one real) intersection parametrizations $ x(t),y(t),z(t)$ between two implicit surfaces?

> p=9;
> ContourPlot3D[{x^2-y-(z-1)^2==1,(x+1)^2+2Sin[3y]-3z==4},{x,-p,p},{y,-p,p},{z,-p,p},AxesLabel->
> {XX,YY,ZZ}]

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your Mathematica code!

Comment: Thanks, given above. Requested intersections parametrizations is  for erg as $t,x(t),y(t),z(t) $.

Comment: Your "time parametrization t"  isn't known!

Comment: Is it possible to output a $Table$ of $(x,y,z)$ coordinates from $ erg $ and $NSolve$  without $t$?

Comment: Yes it's possible, see my modified answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to solve the two  equations for `x,z` to get a parametrization for the intersection curves  `{x[y],y,z[y]}`:

```
erg = Solve[{x^2 - y - (z - 1)^2 == 1, (x + 1)^2 + 2 Sin[3 y] - 3 z ==4}, {x, z}];

Show[{p = 9; 
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 - y - (z - 1)^2 ==1, (x + 1)^2 + 2 Sin[3 y] - 3 z == 4}, {x, -p, p}, {y, -p, p}, {z, -p, p} , Mesh -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z} /. erg, {y, -9, 9}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

The points of intersection follow from

```
pic=ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z} /. erg, {y, -9, 9}, PlotStyle -> Red]
points = Cases[pic, Line[p_] :> p, -1];
Graphics3D@Map[{RandomColor[],Thickness[Large], Line[#]} &, points]
```

[image]